# Querying multiple tables in one .each loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, web-applications

What I am hoping to do is create a timeline of user events pulled from multiple differnt tables that are assosiated with the user.

For example

```
@user.notifications
@user.followings
@user.enrollments
```

I don't know if there is a way to loop through this information sorted by created_at.

like

```
<% (@user.notifications) + (@user.followings) + (@user.enrollments).each do |n, f, e| %>
```

Any guidence would be super appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correctly adding the arrays together (you don't actually need the parans around each element, but you need to wrap the entire adding statement in parans) so now you just need to sort them.

Try this:

```
<% (@user.notifications + @user.followings + @user.enrollments).sort_by(&:created_at).each do |event| %>
```

Comment: except you should only be yielding one element to the block rather than three - maybe just `|event|`

Comment: @MatthewBorg - Thanks for noticing! I've edited my answer.